# How do I add additional snaps to Ubuntu 22.04 Live?

Tags: live-usb, snap, live-cd, preseed

I'm trying to add some snaps to a live USB. I tried the directions given in an answer to  another [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344916/how-to-install-snap-packages-in-cubic), but they don't seem to work on the latest LTS. After following those steps and booting the USB the snaps aren't installed and `snap warnings` shows no warnings. Has something changed in this version or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you add snap based apps to another version of Ubuntu? If so what version?

Comment: @David I haven't tried it myself, the instructions I linked are for 20.04.